# Check if jar file is loaded?

Tags: java, unix, jar, tomcat6

I have a custom jar file in the tomcat lib/ folder. As per my knowledge, any jar file in this folder will be loaded on startup.

Is there anyway I can check if a particular jar file is loaded or not?

I'm running tomcat-6.0.35.A on unix rhel5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think I have seen which jars are open on startup in one of Tomcat log files. If not I could think about two possible alternatives:

1. Add `-verbose:class` to `JAVA_OPTS` in Tomcat startup script. It should print classes as they're loaded by JVM (lots of output). Grep log file (or `stdout`) to find if classes from your jar are listed
2. Use Linux [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) command to see files opened by the Tomcat process.

Comment: `lsof` did answer my question. It helped me see if the jar was being used or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Jars aren't really "loaded on startup". But Tomcat's system class loader is loading classes from those jars. You can check if some class from the jar is available either:

- by trying to load that class from your code, e.g. `getClass().getClassloader().loadClass(className)`
- by trying to load class as a resource, 
  e.g. `getClass().getResource("/" + className.replace('.', '/') + ".class")`

In second case you should have name or your jar file in the url returned by `getResource()`.