# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.getStreamELResolver()Ljavax/el/ELResolver;

Tags: java, tomcat, jstl, tomcat8

I get the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.getStreamELResolver()Ljavax/el/ELResolver;` while using `jstl` in tomcat 8.0.33. I've checked the WEB-INF/lib of my application and it doesn't contain anything that is conflicting.

Also I checked the source code of `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` class from `el-api.jar` file present in tomcat 8's lib folder. The method signature is `public ELResolver getStreamELResolver()`.

This issue occurred after I migrated an application from tomcat 6.0.35 to tomcat 8.0.33. The application was written using `jstl-1.2`

The complete stacktrace is

```
16-May-2016 19:14:54.119 SEVERE [ajp-nio-11009-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.impl.CannotRenderException: org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: JSPException including path '/WEB-INF/JSP/APP/display.jsp'.] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.getStreamELResolver()Ljavax/el/ELResolver;
    at org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<clinit>(ELContextImpl.java:87)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1617)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:750)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:950)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:935)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:673)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)

... (truncated)
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: To be clear, when you say you checked your web application's WEB-INF/lib and "it doesn't contain anything that is conflicting"... you mean that nothing in there contains the class `javax.el.ExpressionFactory`?

Comment: Indeed, the exception suggests otherwise.

Comment: @dcsohl: Yes there is no second version of class `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my application.

Comment: @dcsohl: I've put the IBM remote client jar `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.0.0.jar` in the parent lib of tomcat. Turns out IBM too has `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` for whatsoever reason and that is conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

To tackle such problems of different versions of same class present on the classpath - the best way is to enable verbose class loading and see whether the class is actually being loaded from the intended jar file.

From command line we can run `java -verbose:class MyClassWithMain`. This will output all the classes loaded in the JVM and the name of the jar or any class on the classpath from which it was loaded. Once you find the source of the problem, you can remove it.
To enable `verbose:class` in tomcat, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909334/check-if-jar-file-is-loaded).